# Что нужно знать, перед заказом разработки веб-сервиса в веб-студии?

Tags: веб-программирование

Нужен веб-сервис, своих знаний не хватает. Решил обратиться в веб-студию.

1. Какие подводные камни могут меня ожидать?
2. Как выбрать веб-студию?На что обратить внимание?
3. Какие признаки того, что хотят "Надуть"?
4. Может ли сервис разработанный в "известной" студией приносить реальную прибыль?

Готов потратиться именно на реальную работу.
Не хочу сэкономить, но и не переплатить.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он относится к программированию или системному администрированию слишком отдалённо

Comment: *Может ли сервис разработанный в "известной" студией приносить реальную прибыль?* - откуда вообще берется мнение, что сервис сделанный *известной веб-студией* должен приносить прибыль? разработчики разрабатывают, продвигают маркетологи и продажники.

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте. Для начала необходимо составить полное тз. Также почти все веб-студии берут немаленькую предоплату. Должен быть договор на оказание той или иной услуги, где пишется срок и бюджет проекта.

**Плюсы:**

1. Вам не стоит искать несколько людей отдельно (например front/back-end разработчика);
2. Юридическая защищенность, если есть договор, Вас не кинут 100%;
3. Сроки. Процесс разработки сайтов в веб-студиях регламентирован, и часто зафиксирован в документальном виде документа.

**Минусы:**

1. В веб-студии вы будете всегда переплачивать, причем не мало переплачивать;
2. Срок  реализации проекта дольше, потому что студии более детально подходят к разработке веб-сайта, и у них много стадий взаимодействия, разные исполнители на разных этапах работ, есть накладные расходы, есть обязательства по другим проектам;
3. Если вы нашли ее в интернете, не факт, что это именно студия, на сегодня очень много обычных перекупщиков, которые размещают Ваш заказ на тех же фриланс биржах намного дешевле, чем платите Вы.

Comment: Не все студии берут предоплату при надлежащем оформлении договора.

Comment: @vp_arth   согласен

Answer (score 0):

сервис и веб студия, хм
не смотрите на красивые сайты, красиво сделать сайт - не значит что смогут реализоватеть сервис
Часто приходится сталкиваться с сайтами web студий, где костыль на костыле.
Люди не понимая лепят чтоб это хоть както работало... Снаружи все красиво. Внутри бардак, неоптимизированный код, корявые запросы в циклах, что на странице по 1000 запросов генерится (люди не слышали про join) - результат оно работает, но както все не так и медленно...
продолжать можно сколько угодно, подходите к выбору более трепетно, изучайте есть ли подобный опыт разработок, все зависит от опыта разработчиков фирмы, иначе будут эксперементировать на вас.

Так что вам лучше заручится поддержкой опытного человека, иначе можно будет что то упустить, потом исправлять за своиже деньги.

можно набрать команду на фрилансе, обозначить сроки, стоимость, заключить договора. Будет дешевле, вы напрямую будете общаться с разработчиками.